# Proper use of lambda in function definition

Tags: python, string, lambda, python-3.4

I want to write a simple function that recognizes [palindromes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome):

```
>>> def palindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]
```

It works fine but it is case sensitive and to fix that I could do:

```
>>> def palindrome(s):
    return s.lower() == s[::-1].lower()

>>> palindrome('Aba')
True
```

but I figure it's not very elegant. I tried to lowercase the input by using lambda expressions but I am doing something wrong and don't know how to fix it:

```
>>> def palindrome(lambda s : s.lower()):
    return s == s[::-1]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: No No that is not how `lambda` or arguments work. Why don't you like the second way of doing it?

Comment: You cannot use lambda's in parameter definitions.

Comment: because I'd be lowercasing the string two times, but using lambda, it would be fixed from the start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use a lambda expression to describe actions that should be performed on input parameters (you can however use `lambda` to define a default value). You can do two things:

- Define a function in the head of the function:

  ```
  def palindrome(s):
      s = s.lower()
      return s == s[::-1]
  ```
- Use a *decorator*:

  ```
  def caseinsensitive(f):
      def helper(s):
          s = s.lower()
          return f(s)
      return helper
  ```

  and then define your `palindrome` as:

  ```
  @caseinsensitive
  def palindrome(s):
      return s == s[::-1]
  ```

  Here you can *reuse* the `@caseinsensitive` to define all functions that do this as a first step.

Comment: Nice, this is the answer to my question. It simply can not be done the way I was trying. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Just call lower once, reassign s to the value and forget the lambda:

```
def palindrome(s):
    s = s.lower()
    return s == s[::-1]
```

Comment: You mean `lambda` could not be used here?

Comment: @schmutter, why would you ever want to? You only have to call lower once and return.

Comment: for conciseness and one less line to write.

Comment: @schmutter, two lines is not concise? Moreover the code is readable

Comment: Ok, thanks. But still I would appreciate it if you also show me the way it could be done with lambda.

Comment: You also realise `lambda s : s.lower()` has more characters than `s = s.lower()`?

Comment: @schmutter, you cannot do what you want and to be honest I would not encourage you by trying to code golf an answer.

Comment: Thanks Padraic, I appreciate your answer. Turns out I had a misconception about using lambda's on input parameters. It apparently *cannot* be done from the start.

Comment: @schmutter, no worries, you can see the hack using a lambda actually takes more typing and is less readable so there is no advantage at all using it

Answer (score 6):

This isn't really idiomatic python, but what you're looking for is something like this:

```
def palindrome(s):
    return (lambda x: x == x[::-1])(s.lower())
```

That is, you define a lambda function and immediately invoke it, binding `s.lower()` to `x`.

Comment: Very clever answer! Although it is more readable to what Padraic suggested, this is exactly what the asker is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
def palindrome(s):
    s = s.lower()
    return s == s[::-1]
```

This is pretty straightforward and easy to use and understand answer, which is 100% correct and good.
BUT if you want to use lambda expression you must think how and what  and why and stuff so let's go into the magical world of `FUNCTIONAL PROGRAMMING`.

If you don't know what a `lambda` expression is, basically when you type in the word `lambda` it specifies that you will later on give it some value for instance typing `lambda a` means you will supply it with 1 value (argument), typing `lambda a, b` explicitly means you will suppliy it with 2 values (arguments). So now that this whole thing of "what does even this `lambda` word mean" is done let's go deeper into the magical world of `FUNCTIONAL PROGRAMMING`.

So now when you tell python that it will have to wait some time (or maybe no time at all) for that value so it can do some magic on it, you can tell it what to do with it for instance

```
some_var = lambda some_string: some_string.lower()
```

So now this means that it's going to get some value, we expect it to be some sort of string and we can and will hold it in `some_var` for reasons only `PHP programmers` and us (me) know.

Next up is really straight forward we just return the check whether it is or not a palindrome

```
return some_var == some_var[::-1]
```

Let's get some glue and build this `lambda` beast from the things we have earlier

```
def palindrome():
    some_var = lambda some_string : some_string.lower()
    return some_var == some_var[::-1]
```

As you can see we no longer need to declare that we use some puny `s` in the method, hence we just press `DEL` and we can go along into the beatiful world of `FUNCTIONAL PROGRAMMING`.

So let's try to call this function, but the question raises how to do it?

```
palindrome("superpalindrome") == False
```

It does not compile though, because it thinks we are trying to give the palindrome method some kind of an argument while the definition has none at all. So the correct call of the function should be

```
palindrome()("superpalindrome") == False
```

In short, this is just magic, lambda expressions are actually in most cases worse in case of time usage, so you should stick to doing stuff in a OOP way or even else pythonic way. If you want to use lambda expressions you should try switching to Haskell(which I strongly advise) or Scala. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask me, I love talking about Haskell. Or `FUNCTIONAL PROGRAMMING`.

Full answer that is even more simplified

```
def palindrome():
    return lambda some_str : some_str.lower() == some_str.lower()[::-1]

method = palindrome()

print(method("cococ"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted this:

`(lambda lstr : lstr == lstr[::-1])((lambda x : x.lower())('abA'))`